# WiX (Votive) Project Reference Harvesting (HEAT) an ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, wix, heat, votive

**What I'm Doing**

I have an ASP.Net Web Application and a WiX Setup Project in Visual Studio 2010.  I can explicitly harvest the web application with the following HEAT command set as a pre-build event for the setup project:

> “%WIX%\bin\heat.exe” project "$(SolutionDir)Application.WebUI\Application.WebUI.vbproj" -o "$(ProjectDir)ProjectOutputContent.wxs" -pog Content -ag -template fragment -nologo -directoryid RUNTIMEFOLDER
>
> “%WIX%\bin\heat.exe” project "$(SolutionDir)Application.WebUI\Application.WebUI.vbproj" -o "$(ProjectDir)ProjectOutputBinariesAndSymbols.wxs" -pog Binaries -pog Symbols -ag -template fragment -nologo -directoryid BINFOLDER

Keep in mind that RUNTIME folder and BINFOLDER are directories I declaratively setup in my main product WXS file.

**Why I Don't Like It**

This approach is annoying because I need the HEAT generated fragment WXS files checked out before I can build the setup project.  Another consideration is that it is a web application and I need to drop the binaries and symbols into a different directory (bin) than the content.

**What I'm Aiming For**

I would rather use a project reference within the Wix Setup Project and simply set the Harvest property to True.  I could then harvest the BinariesContentSatellites to get the items I need in my fragment and then set a single Directory Id that I can reference in the main product WXS.  The problem is that this will put the content, binaries and symbols in the same folder where I need the latter two in a nested bin folder.  I can't add this project reference twice, each with different harvest options.

**My Question**

Is there a way to do what I'm after or do I need to keep with the pre-build event?  As an aside, I have considered manually harvesting the fragment once, without a build event, and then re-harvesting as needed.  I would prefer to avoid that approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your topic "Why I Don't Like It" : I too had same problem but then i found the solution. You dont need to check-in the fragment file. Just add the file physically and then include in your project

**Note : Don't add the fragment file from the project.**

Comment: I like what you're thinking.  If someone first pulled this down from source control, the project would look like it was missing files but it would build successfully.  After a build Visual Studio won't immediately show those files as there, but they are.  Re-opening the project again will have them there.

Comment: I am thinking about going with a variation on this approach.  I have added "ProjectOutputBinariesAndSymbols.wxs" and "ProjectOutputContent.wxs" to my compiler additional parameters.  I also added "obj\Debug\ProjectOutputBinariesAndSymbols.wixobj" and "obj\Debug\ProjectOutputContent.wixobj" to my linker additional parameters under Tool Settings for the Wix Setup Project properties screen.

Comment: You can also exclude a file explicitly from source control. Select the file, click File -> Source Control -> (Advanced, in VS2012) -> Exclude ProjectOutputContent.wxs from Source Control. See: http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/2189/69468689.png